# Why does 10BASE-T and 1000BASE-TX Ethernet have two Tx signals?

Tags: ethernet, protocol-theory

In 10BASE-T and 100BASE-TX Ethernet over twisted-pair cable(for example *Cat5e*, *Cat6a*) on PHY level the signals of two endpoints are connected as follows:

```
Tx+ <--> Rx+
Tx- <--> Rx-
Rx+ <--> Tx+
Rx- <--> Tx-
```

This might be a bit of an electrical engineering question, but why there are two Tx signals(obviously two Rx at the receiving end)? If data is transmitted at the same time over Tx+ and Tx-, then does this mean that Ethernet on PHY level is a parallel connection?

Comment: Do you have an extra 0 in 1000BASE-TX? Nobody really uses that.

Comment: OP meant 100BASE-TX; 1000BASE-TX is not a thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> why there are two Tx signals(obviously two Rx at the receiving end)?

It is for [differential signalling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_signaling) to increase noise immunity.

> If data is transmitted at the same time over Tx+ and Tx-, then does this mean that Ethernet on PHY level is a parallel connection?

It is not parallel within a single pair; parallel data transfer involves multiple bit streams.  10/100m Ethernet doesn't leverage parallel data transfer.